# Como obtener la palabra 'myId' de la cadena: /services/#myId en jquery?

Tags: jquery

De la cadena /services/#myId como puedo obtener myId en jquery? la palabra services la obtengo de forma dinámica entonces no siempre va ser services. Ayuda por favor.
Estuve intentando con esto: pero no lo obtengo bien:

```
var myString = '/services/#myId'; //esto puede ser tambien: '/about/#myId2' u 
otro. Siempre lo que necesito es la palabra que está despues de '#'

var mySubString = myString.substring(
        myString.lastIndexOf("/") + 5, 
        myString.lastIndexOf("/")
    );
    console.log(mySubString);
```

Comment: Id no está Definido, pon el código completo

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el método *split*. Con este método lo que haces es, a partir de un string, dividir el mismo según un separador ('#' en tu caso). El resultado es un array con tantas entradas como separadores tenga tu string más uno.

En tu caso, al saber que el separador sólo va a salir una vez, sólo tienes que recoger la segunda entrada del array que devuelve.

```js
var myString = '/services/#myId';

var mySubstring = myString.split('#');
console.log(mySubstring[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```